# How to update values/refresh page after successful AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a very basic auction page which I have now got quite far with. However I would like to update the values of the 'current bid' if the bid has successfully posted via AJAX.

Here is some of my code:

This code retrieves data from MySQL and populates the page.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From auction WHERE category = 'Bathroom' ORDER BY ID DESC");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<form name='auction' id='auction" . $row['ID'] . "'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['ID'] . "' />
            <div class='auction-thumb'>
                <div class='auction-name'>" . $row['Item'] . "</div>";
            echo "<img class='auction' src='" . $row['ImagePath'] . "' />";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Current Bid: £<div class='nospace' id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['CurrentBid'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Name: <input type='text' class='bidder' name='bidname'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Bid: <input type='text' class='auction-text' name='bid'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Place Bid!' /></div>";
    echo "</div></form>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

My jQuery code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form[name="auction"]').submit(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('input[name="id"]').val();
            var bidname = $(this).find('input[name="bidname"]').val();
            var bid = $(this).find('input[name="bid"]').val();
            var currentbid = $('#'+id).text();

            if (bid > currentbid)
            {
                alert("Bid is greater than current bid");   
            }
            else
            {
                return false;   
            }

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auction-handler.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id},
            success: function(data){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;

        }); 
    });
```

The alert is just there for testing purposes. But the jQuery checks the current bid, against the bid that has been submitted in the form.

If the bid has been successfully posted, then I want to update what is shown in the Current Bid, but currently you have to manually refresh the page for this to appear.

I tried adding

```
window.location.reload();
```

on the success section of the AJAX, but nothing happens.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, or alternatively if you know of a better way of doing this then just refreshing the page, please do let me know.

Thank you in advance, and if you need anymore information just let me know.

Comment: use window.location.href='your script name'

Comment: I would recommend [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), it refreshes part of the page and not whole page

Comment: Try location.reload();  or location.href = <url>

Comment: `window.location = window.location` lol first time seeing this does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never enter in the `success` function of your ajax call: You have set the `dataType` to `json` so jQuery expects json back. However, you are sending html back.

You should remove `dataType: "json",` from your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "auction-handler.php",
        // Or remove this, or send json back
        // dataType: "json",
        data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id},
        success: function(data){
            // There is no need for this...
            // window.location.reload();
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Note that the advantage of using ajax is that you can replace parts of the content. So you don't have to reload the whole page, you can just update the section that you want to update.

Comment: @KishorPawar I'm not sure what you mean: It is there but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, removing the dataType has solved my issue and I can now refresh using window.location.reload(); however I am interested in only refreshing the relevant information, but cannot figure how to do that.

Comment: That's where ajax help Barnold as Jeroen said, You set the text using `$('#'+id).text();` or look for jquery load() function

Comment: @Barnold You should probably ask a new question posting the new code and where you have a problem exactly.

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax response you can simply pass the new bid value to the element and there is no need to refresh the whole page. in your ajax function return the proper value and then replace it.

```
success: function(data) 
{
  ('#element-id').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assign data.bid (which is send by the server)to  currentbid in the ajax success.

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "auction-handler.php",
                data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id},
                success: function(data) {
                    currentbid = data.bid   // bid from server    
                }
            });
```